# How to change the directory of blog posts in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, directory, blogs

First time user here:
I am wondering how you can change the directory of blog posts from www.yoursite.com/node/... to www.yoursite.com/blog/...?

Comment: OK, I don't know how to follow up here, but I am already using the Pathauto module suggested by Dusan, so how you can change the DEFAULT directory path to be blog/ and not node/ on content types created as blog entrys?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to define an alias for "blog entry" nodes.

EDIT:

Then go to www.yoursite.com/admin/build/path/pathauto, under "Node path settings", put something like `blog/[title-raw]` in "Pattern for Blog entry path".

Finally go to www.yoursite.com/admin/content/node, select all your blog entries, and select "Update path alias" under "Update options".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am using the Pathauto module and the default is still node/. So how can I change this default?